# How to take Amazon backup

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

How to I take backup of my mysql rds instance from amazon rds service.
and what is the available options to take a backup? 
Means I want to take a backup daily, weekly and hourly, where I have to configure it, and amazon where to store that backups.

Comment: Question for dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

AWS basically provided two options for DB backup: **`automated backups`** and **`database snapshots`**.

When automated backups are turned on, Amazon RDS automatically performs a full daily snapshot of your data (during your preferred backup window) and captures transaction logs. By default and at no additional charge, Amazon RDS enables automated backups of your DB Instance with a 1 day retention period, but that's configurable. You can use `ModifyDBInstance API` to change the existing DB settings.

DB Snapshots are user-initiated and enable you to back up your DB Instance in a known state as frequently as you wish.

DB snapshots and automated backups are stored in S3.

**Edit** after datasage's comment:

I found this discussion [What are the pros/cons of hosting a MySQL DB in Amazon RDS versus a DB instance in EC2](http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-pros-cons-of-hosting-a-MySQL-DB-in-Amazon-RDS-versus-a-DB-instance-in-EC2). It talks about the problems of using MyISAM tables.

Comment: One thing to add. If you want to take advantage of automated backups you are best off using innodb tables. While MyISAM is supported, it does not support transactions and might result in inconsistent states if you restore from backup.

Comment: @datasage, very good point. +1

Answer (score 2):

The RDS console allows you to set the backup options (frequency, how many to keep and so on) you don't need to worry about storage RDS does that for you.

If you want to backup an RDS instance outside RDS, then it depends on which type of database you are hosting on RDS, MySQL, Oracle or SQLServer - each have their own backup tools.

Comment: I am using mysql as database. and how can I download that backup on my local PC?

Comment: hey, were you able to find out, i am having the same problem...

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get the database backup to your local system,here is a  bash script which does it for you. https://github.com/jeevandongre/aws-repo (I wrote this script and made it open source)

Comment: That script does not solve downloading backup (the original question), but installation of all AWS tools.